# ng-if tabs condition display div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, angular-ng-if

Hello I need to display a div only if tabs[0].active. I am trying to write a good condition but i can not handle this. I tried 3 ways:

```
<div ng-if="tabs[0].active">
```

and

```
<div ng-if="tabs.title == 'Dodawanie opisu'">
```

and

```
<div ng-if="tabs(title == 'Dodawanie opisu')">
```

any of them ain't work fine for me. Tabs is an array. I am using script like this one:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgdQgv

What am i missing here?

Comment: `<div ng-if="tabs[0].active">` should do it if `tabs[0].active === true`.  Do you have tabs on the scope?

Comment: My JS file is very similar to this one I paste in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgdQgv

Comment: tabs[0].active === true doesnt work aswell :(